# MySQL how to query five tables in one SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables as follows:

- **tbl_individ** - consists of user data (*uID, Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, eMail*)
- **tbl_role** - consists of roles (*rID, Rolename, RoleDescription*)
- **tbl_group** - consists of groups (*gID, Groupname, GroupDescription*)
- **tbl_inro** - consists of which roles a user has (*uID, rID*)
- **tbl_ingr** - consists of which groups a user belongs to (*uID, gID*)

I'd like to achieve the output where I list all the users in the **tbl_individ** and list what each user what roles they has and as well what groups they belong to.

I created the **tbl_inro** to only map the user (uID) and the role (rID) and the same for the **tbl_ingr** to only map the user (uID) and the group (gID).

It all as output in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the users groups and roles in a single row, I think you're looking for something like `group_concat`. So something like

```
SELECT tbl_individ.uID, tbl_individ.Firstname, tbl_individ.Lastname, tbl_individ.Mobile, tbl_individ.eMail, 
 group_concat(Groupname separator ', ') as groups, 
 group_concat(Rolename separator ', ') as roles
FROM tbl_individ LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_inro
  ON tbl_inro.uid = tbl_individ.uid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_role
  ON tbl_role.rid = tbl_inro.rid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_ingr
  ON tbl_ingr.uid = tbl_individ.uid
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_group
  ON tbl_group.gid = tbl_ingr.gid
GROUP BY tbl_individ.uID, tbl_individ.Firstname, tbl_individ.Lastname, tbl_individ.Mobile, tbl_individ.eMail
```

Comment: Note that group_concat will truncate after a server-variable-determined number of characters (not a problem, but something to be aware of)

Comment: This will repeat each Groupname as many times as there are roles if there are multiple roles for a user and each Rolename as many times as there are groups if there are multiple groups for a user.  Use `group_concat(distinct ...)` instead (though that will only show each name once, even if there are multiple groups/roles with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I've JOIN'd the tables using INNER JOIN. You can use LEFT JOIN if that better suits. This has basically taken common fields and linked them together as requested.

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        tbl_individ tbl_ind
INNER JOIN  tbl_inro tbl_inro
ON          tbl_inro.uID = tbl_ind.uID
INNER JOIN  tbl_role tbl_role
ON          tbl_role.rID = tbl_inro.rID
INNER JOIN  tbl_ingr tbl_ingr
ON          tbl_ingr.uID = tbl_ind.uID
INNER JOIN  tbl_group tbl_group
ON          tbl_group.gID = tbl_ingr.gID
```

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: Thank you for your input. OP can work it out based on their own needs.